# \usepackage{listings} with sffamily but proportional

Tags: fonts, listings, code, sans-serif

I'm using `\usepackage{listings}` to display code in a text. With `basicstyle=\sffamily`, the text is displayed sans serif, but I want to have it proportianal too. Is any one know if it possible to have sans serif proportional font?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As fa as I know, sans serif fonts are proporcional fonts. What is the problem then?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily]
I'm using \usepackage{listings} to display code in a text. With basicstyle=\sffamily, the text is 
displayed sans serif, but I want to have it proportianal too. Is any one know if it possible to 
have sans serif proportional font?
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=fullflexible]
I'm using \usepackage{listings} to display code in a text. With basicstyle=\sffamily, the text is 
displayed sans serif, but I want to have it proportianal too. Is any one know if it possible to 
have sans serif proportional font?
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), note that besides `fullflexible` there is also `flexible` and `spaceflexible` that are still proportional but a bit less condensed.

Comment: My best wishes for your 10k of reputation: just it was 9999. I am very happy for to have give you my upvoted.

Comment: good answer indeed. Thanks, it helps me a lot